# Does Samung Galaxy S2 support the use of Client Certificates for ActiveSync?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, certificates, active-sync

Does Samung Galaxy S2 support the use of Client Certificates for ActiveSync ?

Most other Android phones need to rely on TouchDown or other third party applications. Can anyone confirm if this is possible on the new Galaxy S 2.

My exchange server implements the use of Client Certificates (.pfx).

Thanks,cyphr

Comment: The default Email app is awful, I really would not expect it to support certificates.

Comment: The videos showed a pretty nice app - one that switches to a split screen (tab-like) layout. Have you tried setting up ACtive Sync ?